# Magento 2: send email with Attachment

Tags: magento2, email, attachment

How to send email with a file attachment.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

M2 does not come with out of the box however it is a feature built into the zend framework.  Here is a good reference how to add this functionality into magento: https://blog.bitexpert.de/blog/sending-mails-with-attachments-in-magento-2/

In case link goes dead, create the following

```
<?php
namespace Your\CustomModule\Magento\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder 
    extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addAttachment(
        $body,
        $mimeType    = Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename    = null
    ) {
        $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

then add to etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder"
                type="\Your\CustomModule\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

Now you can use `addAttachment()` throughout your site.

Comment: I still wonder why magento TransportBuilder does not have this method

Comment: How can we attached file in custom email magento 2.3 ? because its using zendframework 2 and this answer not working any more

Comment: How to Send Email with Attachment in Magento 2.3?

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari & Mitesh Have you got the solution?

Comment: This solution is not working in Magento2.3 anymore. Is anyone have alternative for attachment.?

Comment: I added an answer that works for 2.3 below. Hope that helps! Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't work in Magento 2.2.11. Try @Jean-Bernard Valentaten answer it may help.

Answer (score 17):

As of Magento 2.2.7 the solutions described above do not work anymore since `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Message` dropped extending `\Zend_Mail`.
To circumvent the lack of an easy way to add attachments through the transport builder (which currently seems to be the correct place for such a function), one needs to create a replacement for the TransportBuilder and make use `\Zend\Mime\Part`:

```php
<?php
namespace Your\CustomModule\Magento\Mail\Template;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\Part as MimePart;
use Zend\Mime\PartFactory as MimePartFactory;
use Zend\Mime\Message as MimeMessage;
use Zend\Mime\MessageFactory as MimeMessageFactory;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /** @var MimePart[] */
    private $parts = [];

    /** @var MimeMessageFactory */
    private $mimeMessageFactory;

    /** @var MimePartFactory */
    private $mimePartFactory;

    public function __construct(
        FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
        MessageInterface $message,
        SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory,
        MimePartFactory $mimePartFactory,
        MimeMessageFactory $mimeMessageFactory,
        MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $templateFactory,
            $message,
            $senderResolver,
            $objectManager,
            $mailTransportFactory,
            $messageFactory
        );

        $this->mimePartFactory    = $mimePartFactory;
        $this->mimeMessageFactory = $mimeMessageFactory;
    }

    protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        parent::prepareMessage();

        $mimeMessage = $this->getMimeMessage($this->message);

        foreach ($this->parts as $part) {
            $mimeMessage->addPart($part);
        }

        $this->message->setBody($mimeMessage);

        return $this;
    }

    public function addAttachment(
        $body,
        $mimeType = Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename = null
    ) {
        $this->parts[] = $this->createMimePart($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        return $this;
    }

    private function createMimePart(
        $content,
        $type = Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename = null
    ) {
        /** @var MimePart $mimePart */
        $mimePart = $this->mimePartFactory->create(['content' => $content]);
        $mimePart->setType($type);
        $mimePart->setDisposition($disposition);
        $mimePart->setEncoding($encoding);

        if ($filename) {
            $mimePart->setFileName($filename);
        }

        return $mimePart;
    }

    private function getMimeMessage(MessageInterface $message)
    {
        $body = $message->getBody();

        if ($body instanceof MimeMessage) {
            return $body;
        }

        /** @var MimeMessage $mimeMessage */
        $mimeMessage = $this->mimeMessageFactory->create();

        if ($body) {
            $mimePart = $this->createMimePart((string)$body, Mime::TYPE_TEXT, Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
            $mimeMessage->setParts([$mimePart]);
        }

        return $mimeMessage;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace the original `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder` by your implementation via `di.xml`.

Note that this implementation will probably break with an upcoming release of Magento as `\Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface::setBody()` is deprecated and may be removed soonish.

HTH

Comment: Hi! You have a method addAttachment in your code, but where did you call them? I don't see it.

Comment: thanks! I added loop to prepareMessage method and everithing works.

Comment: @NikolaiSilin how to send a png or other files.

Comment: @Jean-Bernard Valentaten it worked in Magento 2.2.11, thank you so much this saves a lot of time

Answer (score 13):

### Magento 2.3.x Compatible:

This was my answer for Magento 2.3 since this was a top question on google and there seems to be a lot of people in the comments looking.

There seems to be a lot of desire in other posts about overwriting the default `TransportBuilder` class via `etc/di.xml`, however the module I'm working on is so small that I don't want it to be responsible for the default `TransportBuilder` so I built a Helper class (should probably be a model based on how coupled it is to the declared email template - but I digress).

The `TransportBuilder` doesn't have public access to the `TransportInterface`, but instead generates a clone everytime and then resets the builder. I found it easier to build my `TransportInterface` instance and then attach my attachment `Part` objects to the transport's message. If you do find it necessary to overwrite the default `TransportBuilder` via dependency injection preference, be careful about updating public methods. Remember to practice the [O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) when keeping your code [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)!

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Zend_Mime;
use Zend\Mime\Part;

/**
 * This was initially built out to send a single email. Abstract this as you 
 * wish.
 *
 * @package Vendor\Module\Helper
 */
class Mail extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    protected $context;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * Mail constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param Config $config
     * @param File $file
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Config $config,
        File $file
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Send the email for a Help Center submission.
     *
     * @param DataObject $templateParams
     * @param array $attachments
     * @return void
     */
    public function send(DataObject $templateParams, array $attachments = [])
    {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        // Build transport
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface $transport */
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->config->getEmailTemplate())
            ->setTemplateVars($templateParams->toArray())
            ->setFrom($this->config->getEmailSender())
            ->addTo($this->config->getEmailRecipient(), 'Help Center')
            /**
             * Something important to note is that when the getTransport()
             * function is run, the message is compiled and then the builder 
             * class resets (as of 2.3.1). 
             * 
             * This is note worthy because if you want to send > 1 attachment,
             * your $builder will be reset -- losing all of the ->set* functions
             * you just used above as well as your attachment.
             * 
             * Since we append attachments to the transport, it's easier to:
             * build -> attach -> send. And this way multiple attachments 
             * can be included. :thumbsup:
             */
            ->getTransport();

        // Attach Images to transport
        foreach ($attachments as $a) {
            $transport = $this->addAttachment($transport, $a);
        }

        // Send transport
        $transport->sendMessage();
    }

    /**
     * Add an attachment to the message inside the transport builder.
     *
     * @param TransportInterface $transportBuilder
     * @param array $file Sanitized index from $_FILES
     * @return TransportInterface
     */
    protected function addAttachment(TransportInterface $transport, array $file): TransportInterface
    {
        $part = $this->createAttachment($file);
        $transport->getMessage()->getBody()->addPart($part);

        return $transport;
    }

    /**
     * Create an zend mime part that is an attachment to attach to the email.
     * 
     * This was my usecase, you'll need to edit this to your own needs.
     *
     * @param array $file Sanitized index from $_FILES
     * @return Part
     */
    protected function createAttachment(array $file): Part
    {
        $ext =  '.' . explode('/', $file['type'])[1];
        $fileName = md5(uniqid(microtime()), true) . $ext;

        $attachment = new Part($this->file->read($file['tmp_name']));
        $attachment->disposition = Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM;
        $attachment->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
        $attachment->filename = $fileName;

        return $attachment;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get it to work properly, I always get an exception saying "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addPart() on string"... any idea about that? :/

Comment: @hallleron Oddly enough this is different than what I was getting, but it looks like you're correct. The `MessageInterface::getBody` method signature shows a string return type. You might have to dig around in your `TransportInterface` object, but I can tell you that the `addPart` method exists on a `Zend\Mime\Message` object. Since magento likely extended that class for their own `Message` class, I think it would be smart to try `$transport->getMessage()->addpart($part);`

Comment: How to apply this in Magento 2.3?

Comment: getBody() call was missing before addPart() call. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you @RomanSnitko

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 Custom email from Module, Doesn't provide image attachment.

If you want to use Image attachment with email templates in Magento 2 you need to override class, **Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder**

Magento Out-of-box doesn't provide attachment feature for email. You can refer blogs for send image attachment in details,

You need to add logic like below way,

```
 public function addAttachment(
        $body,
        $mimeType    = \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding    = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename    = null
    ) {
        $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Can you help  to achieve same in magento 2.3 ?

Comment: Created attachments in this way until 2.2.7. 2.2.8 and 2.3+ are not working

Comment: I just posted an answer for 2.3.x @MatthiasKleine

Comment: hello,how can i attach if i have base64 encoding string?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the previous answers, magento2 does not have a function out-of-the-box to send mails with attachments.

I don't know if it is a best practice, but you could call directly `Zend_Mail` class to do it, without create a custom function and override `Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder`, like below

```
$mail = new \Zend_Mail('utf-8');
$mail->setFrom($senderEmail);
$mail->addTo($receiverEmail);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBodyHtml($text);

$content = file_get_contents($attachmentAbsolutePath);

$attachment = new \Zend_Mime_Part($content);
$attachment->type = 'text/xml'; // attachment's mime type
$attachment->disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
$attachment->encoding = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$attachment->filename = $filename;
$mail->addAttachment($attachment);
$mail->send();
```

Comment: before give -1, it is suggested by so to use this comment textarea, then everyone could understand what is wrong, thx

Comment: $transport->getMessage()->setBody($bodyPart);

Comment: getting this Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Framework\\Mail\\EmailMessage::setBody()

Comment: These comments are not related to the answer

Comment: i am getting this error in magento 2.3.3

Comment: in the above answer there isn't `$transport` variable, why you comment here?

Comment: @imtiazau Did u find any solution and it seems i am facing the same error of what u r facing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is perfect answer to send pdf in Email in magetno 2.3

```
$transport = $_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(20)
    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)                                                 
    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->addTo($vendor_email)
    ->getTransport();

$html = $transport->getMessage()>getBody()->generateMessage();            
$bodyMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Part($html);
$bodyMessage->type = 'text/html';
$attachment = $_transportBuilder->addAttachment($pdfData,$fileName);      
$bodyPart = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
$bodyPart->setParts(array($bodyMessage,$attachment));
$transport->getMessage()->setBody($bodyPart);                
$transport->sendMessage();
$inlineTranslation->resume();
```

Comment: Hi, It is throwing a fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function generateMessage() on null

Comment: You're creating a new message which is unnecessary when your transport already has a message. Why not just add a part to the one in place? This is messy and hard to follow. Not to mention you're doubling the work and memory needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Override  \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="TM\ShipmentEmail\Model\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

Define this constant if you need in overrides file and add following data

```
const MIME_TYPES = [
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'jpg' => 'image/jpg'
    ];
    
  //check file type  
protected function prepareMessage()
{
$snapshotFileTypes = self::MIME_TYPES[ (string) substr($snapshot, strrpos($snapshot, '.') + 1); ];

 //call for attachment in custom function    
        $this->addAttachment(file_get_contents($fullSnapshotPath), $endSnap, $snapshotFileType );
}
       // finally add attachment in this funtion

        public function addAttachment(?string $content, ?string $fileName, ?string $fileType)
        {
            $attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();
            $attachmentPart->setContent($content)
                ->setType($fileType)
                ->setFileName($fileName)
                ->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
                ->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
            $this->attachments[] = $attachmentPart;
    
            return $this;
        }
```