# Add CSV to order emails

Tags: magento2, email, csv

How can I programmatically add a CSV containing all order information to order emails. By default only a PDF is attached to those emails.

I know I have to write a plugin. But I don't know which class or method I have to modify and how.

Comment: Can you please share  code where default only a PDF is attached?

Comment: @AmitBera: Here my problem starts. I don't know where the PDF is attached.

Comment: Please see the article below : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104044/magento-2-send-email-with-attachment