# How to Add Attachment with email magento 2.3?

Tags: email, magento2.3, attachment

Can anyone help us on Add Attachment with email Magento 2.3? We have tried but face the same issue like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252506/magento-2-3-custom-email-attachment-not-working).

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor::createAttachment() in Mail/TransportBuilder.php

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Go through the following link, it may help you. https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-attach-a-pdf-file-to-emails-in-magento-2/

Comment: Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: No working @PremaKarthik

Comment: @SukumarGorai no need to add a code createAttachment() is deprecated on zf2. So, I want alternate solutions for that.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. found any solution?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Did you solved that ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Did you solve the issue? I have same issue in magento 2.2.11

Answer (score 2):

https://extait.com/blog/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3/

As from above link add encoding concept..

```
 public function setBodyAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType)
{
    $attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();
    $attachmentPart->setContent($content)
        ->setType($fileType)
        ->setFileName($fileName)
        ->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_BASE64) /*Add this*/
        ->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT);

    $this->parts[] = $attachmentPart;

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave the advice [there](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252506/magento-2-3-custom-email-attachment-not-working) already. 
Try the method described here -  https://extait.com/blog/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3/ as well as links provided to GitHub to see a sample module.

Comment: It's stop the email with error "Unable to send email unknow error" .

Comment: @SameerBhayani  That's strange. I use this module https://github.com/extait-com/email-attachment and it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

1) in your custom transport builder add the below function for atatchment:

```
<?php namespace Magebees\Demo\Model\Mail;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /**
     * @param Api\AttachmentInterface $attachment
     */
    public function addAttachment($pdfString,$filename)
    {
       $attachment = new \Zend\Mime\Part($pdfString);
            $attachment->type = \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM;
            $attachment->disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
            $attachment->encoding = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
            $attachment->filename = $filename;
        return $attachment;
}
}
```

2) Then where you have used
     $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport(); in that file
    add below code for send mail

```
$html='my testing html';            
            $bodyMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Part($html);
            $bodyMessage->type = 'text/html';
            $attachment=$this->_transportBuilder->addAttachment($pdfString,$pdf_name);      
            $bodyPart = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
            $bodyPart->setParts(array($bodyMessage,$attachment));
            $transport->getMessage()->setBody($bodyPart);
 $transport->sendMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by extending Magento\Framework\Mail\Message and adding new function createCustomAttachment in this, also edited the createHtmlMimeFromString function.

protected $attachment;

```
public function createCustomAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename){
    $attachment = new Part($body);
    $attachment->setType($mimeType);
    $attachment->setDisposition($disposition);
    $attachment->setEncoding($encoding);
    $attachment->setFileName($filename);
    $this->attachment = $attachment;
    return $this;
}
```

Called the global variable $this->attachment in the function createHtmlMimeFromString. If the variable has value then we are adding the attachment data to the addPart function.

The code be like this

```
private function createHtmlMimeFromString($htmlBody)
{
    $htmlPart = new Part($htmlBody);
    $htmlPart->setCharset($this->zendMessage->getEncoding());
    $htmlPart->setType(Mime::TYPE_HTML);
    $mimeMessage = new \Zend\Mime\Message();
    $mimeMessage->addPart($htmlPart);
    if ($this->attachment) {
        $mimeMessage->addPart($this->attachment);
    }

    return $mimeMessage;
}
```

We need to copy the Magento\Framework\Mail\Message entire content in the extended file because the zendMessage is private and this is called in almost all functions.

We can call the createCustomAttachment function from the transport builder to pass the attachment details.

```
public function addAttachment($body,
                              $mimeType = Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                              $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                              $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                              $filename = null)
{
    //$this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
    $this->message->createCustomAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
    return $this;
}
```