# How to send transactional mail with attachment in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, transactional-mail, attachment

How can I send email with attachment in magento 2.3.I already tried the way of custom  TransportBuilder class from many answer but not working at all.I'm new to magento pls help me.

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution after two day.Here I found the module for magento 2.3 email attachment for anyone who face the problem like me.

Module Repo
https://github.com/extait-com/email-attachment

Tutorial
https://extait.com/blog/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3/

Thanks Extait

Answer (score 0):

For Override **TransportBuilder.php** file in Magento 2, you need to create **di.xml** file.

Using **di.xml** file you can override any PHP class in Magento 2.

Create **di.xml** in your module,

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <!-- Mail sending with attachment -->
   <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

Create **TransportBuilder.php** file at below location,

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
 public function addAttachment(
    $body,
    $mimeType    = \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
    $disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $encoding    = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
    $filename    = null
) {
    $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
    return $this;
}
}
```

Create helper file to send image attachment in mail template,

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Helper;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const EMAIL_IDENTIFIER_TEMPLATE = 'custommodule/general/emailtemplate';

    protected $_inlineTranslation;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_transportBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder    ) 
    {
        $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function mailSend() {

        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $templateName = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::EMAIL_IDENTIFIER_TEMPLATE,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );

        $senderName = 'Sender name'; //store admin sender name
        $senderEmail = 'senderemailid@xyz.com'; // store admin email id
        $recipientEmail = 'recipientemail@xyz.com'; // recipient email id
        $recipientName = 'recipient name';

        if (!$senderEmail && !$recipientEmail) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateName)
            ->setTemplateOptions([
                'area'  => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $storeId,
            ])
            ->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    'order' => 'custom order data',
                    'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
                ]
            );
           /*  image attachment logic */
            $image = 'abc.jpg'; //actual image name
            $mediaPath = 'image_dynamic_file_path'.$image; //set image path
            $body = file_get_contents($mediaPath);
            $imageName = pathinfo($image,PATHINFO_BASENAME);
            $this->_transportBuilder->addAttachment(
                $body,
                'image/jpeg',
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                $imageName
            );

        $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setFrom([
                'name'  => $senderName,
                'email' => $senderEmail,
            ])
            ->addTo($recipientEmail, $recipientName);

        /* @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport $transport */
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();

        try {
            $transport->sendMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->context->getLogger()->alert($e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
    }
 }
```

**Note:** In above example i send image attachment

I hope it works! Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I already tried that way not working in magento 2.3.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252506/magento-2-3-custom-email-attachment-not-working?rq=1

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: call undefined method createAttachment() error.