# Magento 2.3.2 custom email send createAttachment() method is not working

Tags: email, email-templates, magento2.3.2, attachment

**custom email send createAttachment() method** is not working how to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2.3 custom email attachment not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252506/magento-2-3-custom-email-attachment-not-working)

Comment: using SMTP ???/

Comment: Use this method in TransportBuilder class public function addAttachment( $pdfString, $enable )
    {
        if ($enable) {
                $obj = new Zend_Mail;
                $obj->createAttachment($pdfString,
                'application/pdf',
                \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                'Estimate_Quote.pdf') ;
        }
        return $this;
    }