# Magento :2.3 addAttachement() is not working

Tags: magento2, email

I got the below error while using **addAttachement** function in my cron file.

```
[2019-09-13 06:31:20] main.CRITICAL: Error when running a cron job {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Error when running a cron job at C:\
ew\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\vendor\\magento\\module-cron\\Observer\\ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:327, Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method Magento\\Framework\\Mail\\Template\\TransportBuilder\\Interceptor::addAttachment() at C:\
ew\\xampp\\htdocs\\Project\\app\\code\\KiwiCommerce\\AdminActivity\\Cron\\Test.php:62)"} []
```

I have shared my current code below please check and if possible to help me.

```
<?php
/**
 * KiwiCommerce
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade to newer versions in the future.
 * If you wish to customize this module for your needs.
 * Please contact us https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/contacts.
 *
 * @category   KiwiCommerce
 * @package    KiwiCommerce_AdminActivity
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2018 Kiwi Commerce Ltd (https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/)
 * @license    https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/magento2-extension-license/
 */
namespace KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Cron;

use KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;

/**
 * Class ClearLog
 * @package KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Cron
 */
class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    const TEST_TEMPLATE_IDENTIFIER = 'modulename_test_template';
    const TEST_FROM_EMAIL = 'general';
    const TEST_TO_EMAIL = 'akhil.mokariya@fghgh.com';
    const TEST_FILE_CONTENT = 'Test file content.';
    const TEST_FILE_NAME = 'test';
    const TEST_FILE_TYPE = 'txt';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    protected $state;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder, 
        State $state
    )
    {
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->state = $state;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            // $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_FRONTEND);

            $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier(self::TEST_TEMPLATE_IDENTIFIER)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => 1])
                ->setTemplateVars([])
                ->addAttachment(self::TEST_FILE_CONTENT, self::TEST_FILE_NAME, self::TEST_FILE_TYPE)
                ->setFrom(self::TEST_FROM_EMAIL)
                ->addTo(self::TEST_TO_EMAIL)
                ->getTransport()
                ->sendMessage();
            print_r(__('Everything is fine, email has been sent.'));
        } catch (MailException $me) {
            print_r(__('MailException: %1', $me->getMessage()));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            print_r(__('Exception: %1', $e->getMessage()));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`addAttachment()`, is not available anymore on 2.3 you should use Zend\Mime .

You can follow this links for more helpful info and solution.

- > https://extait.com/blog/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3/
- > http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2019/05/22/sending-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3-x/
- > [Magento 2.3 custom email attachment not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252506/magento-2-3-custom-email-attachment-not-working)