# How to attach file in email in magento 2.3.5-p2 laminas

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.5-p2, email-attachment

i want to attach file in email

**magento 2.3.5-p2**

now they removed Zend Framework now they are using **laminas**

> how i can attach file in email?
>
> in previous versions
>
> i have used this code to work with but
>
> now latest versions not working

https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-attachments-with-email-in-magento-2-3-x/

any one have any source or blogs to solve this problem?

Comment: i have found https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-mail/message/attachments/

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/297997/82670