# Email Attachment not working in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.2.6, email-attachment

I am using Magento version 2.2.6 and trying to send custom email with attachment, but I am getting 500 error.
I tried transportbuilder addattachment which is working in Magento 2.3.x and onwards.
But facing issue in this version.

I am trying this code:

```
  $this->message->createAttachment(
            $pdfString,
            'application/pdf',
            \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
            'attatched.pdf'
        );
```

And getting this error [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/civfS.png

Kindly let me know how I can send email with attachment in Magento version 2.2.6.

Any help will be apperciated.

Comment: Which error you are facing?

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/298001/82670

Comment: And also try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252506/magento-2-3-custom-email-attachment-not-working/297997

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
$this->message->createAttachment(
                $pdfString,
               \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
               \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
               \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
               'attatched.pdf'
             );
```