# Received email pdf display no name

Tags: magento2.3.4

**i have created custom form module that send the email with pdf,
attachment sends but in email it shows no name, in image it shows error**,[image]

My Code..........
**TransportBuilder.php**
app/code/Vendor/Module/Magento/Mail/Template

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Magento\Mail\Template;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\Part as MimePart;
use Zend\Mime\PartFactory as MimePartFactory;
use Zend\Mime\Message as MimeMessage;
use Zend\Mime\MessageFactory as MimeMessageFactory;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /** @var MimePart[] */
    private $parts = [];

    /** @var MimeMessageFactory */
    private $mimeMessageFactory;

    /** @var MimePartFactory */
    private $mimePartFactory;

    public function __construct(
        FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
        MessageInterface $message,
        SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory,
        MimePartFactory $mimePartFactory,
        MimeMessageFactory $mimeMessageFactory,
        MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $templateFactory,
            $message,
            $senderResolver,
            $objectManager,
            $mailTransportFactory,
            $messageFactory
        );

        $this->mimePartFactory    = $mimePartFactory;
        $this->mimeMessageFactory = $mimeMessageFactory;
    }

    protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        parent::prepareMessage();

        $mimeMessage = $this->getMimeMessage($this->message);

        foreach ($this->parts as $part) {
            $mimeMessage->addPart($part);
        }

        $this->message->setBody($mimeMessage);

        return $this;
    }

    public function addAttachment(
        $body,
        $mimeType = Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename = null
    ) {
        $this->parts[] = $this->createMimePart($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        return $this;
    }

    private function createMimePart(
        $content,
        $type = Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename = null
    ) {
        /** @var MimePart $mimePart */
        $mimePart = $this->mimePartFactory->create(['content' => $content]);
        $mimePart->setType($type);
        $mimePart->setDisposition($disposition);
        $mimePart->setEncoding($encoding);

        if ($filename) {
            $mimePart->setFileName($filename);
        }

        return $mimePart;
    }

    private function getMimeMessage(MessageInterface $message)
    {
        $body = $message->getBody();

        if ($body instanceof MimeMessage) {
            return $body;
        }

        /** @var MimeMessage $mimeMessage */
        $mimeMessage = $this->mimeMessageFactory->create();

        if ($body) {
            $mimePart = $this->createMimePart((string)$body, Mime::TYPE_TEXT, Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
            $mimeMessage->setParts([$mimePart]);
        }

        return $mimeMessage;
    }
}
```

**Post.phtml**
app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Zend\Log\Filter\Timestamp;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_NAME = 'trans_email/ident_support/name';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_EMAIL = 'trans_email/ident_support/email';

    protected $_inlineTranslation;
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_logLoggerInterface;

      private $fileUploaderFactory;
        private $fileSystem; 
        //protected $_transportBuilder;
        //protected $inlineTranslation;
        //protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
         \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
         Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
        array $data = []

        )
    {
        $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_logLoggerInterface = $loggerInterface;
        $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();  
        $this->fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->fileSystem          = $fileSystem;       
        parent::__construct($context);                  
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($post); die();
       // $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('attachment');
       // print_r($filesData);die;
        try
        {

           $filesData = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('attachment');

            if ($filesData['name']) {
             $uploader = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'attachment']);
             $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
             $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
             $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
             $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('test-doc');
             $result = $uploader->save($path);
             $attachment = 'test-doc'.$uploader->getUploadedFilename();
             $filePath = $result['path'].$result['file'];
             $fileName = $result['name'];
        } else {
             $attachment = '';
             $filePath = '';
             $fileName = '';
        }


            // Send Mail
            $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

            $senderName = $post['name'];
            $senderAddress = $post['address'];
            $senderCity = $post['city'];
            $senderState = $post['state'];
            $senderZipcode = $post['zipcode'];
            $senderEmail = $post['email'];            
            $senderHomephone = $post['homephone'];
            $senderCellphone = $post['cellphone'];
            $senderSalesexperience = $post['salesexperience'];



            $sender = [
                'name' => $post['name'],
                'address' => $post['address'],
                'city' => $post['city'],                
                'state' => $post['state'],
                'zipcode' => $post['zipcode'],
                'email' => $post['email'],
                'homephone' => $post['homephone'],
                'cellphone' => $post['cellphone'],
                'salesexperience' => $post['salesexperience']
            ];

            $sentToEmail = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

            $sentToName = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);


            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('customemail_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => 'frontend',
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars([
                    'name' => $post['name'],
                    'address' => $post['address'],
                    'city' => $post['city'],                
                    'state' => $post['state'],
                    'zipcode' => $post['zipcode'],
                    'email' => $post['email'],
                    'homephone' => $post['homephone'],
                    'cellphone' => $post['cellphone'],
                    'salesexperience' => $post['salesexperience']
                ])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($sentToEmail,$sentToName)
                ->addAttachment($filePath, $fileName)
                //->addTo('owner@example.com','owner')*/
                ->getTransport();

                $transport->sendMessage();

                $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Email sent successfully');
                $this->_redirect('customemail/index/index');

        } catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

i dont know where is the mistake..
pls help me..
tthanks

Comment: Can you show email template for this? I mean view file

Comment: which version of Magento you use ?

Comment: try this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/magento-2-3-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3-use-zendframework-2/298001#298001

Answer (score 0):

you put null in your file name  in **TransportBuilder.php**

```
public function addAttachment(
        $body,
        $mimeType = Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename = *<here get cuurent file name>*
    ) {
        $this->parts[] = $this->createMimePart($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: The $filename already pass in Function so it's don't need to define it again. Because Filename are coming from function parameters. So simple remove $filename

Answer (score 0):

use this for encoding

```
$encoding = '8bit'
```