# Magento 2: How to override file Mail.php

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to override this file :`vendor\magento\module-contact\Model\Mail.php`

> vendor/module/Model/Mail.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace vendor\module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;

class Mail
{
    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $contactsConfig;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StateInterface
     */
    private $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param ConfigInterface $contactsConfig
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param StoreManagerInterface|null $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->contactsConfig = $contactsConfig;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Send email from contact form
     *
     * @param string $replyTo
     * @param array $variables
     * @return void
     */
    public function send($replyTo, array $variables)
    {
        /** @see \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::validatedParams() */
        $replyToName = !empty($variables['data']['name']) ? $variables['data']['name'] : null;

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($variables)
                ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
                ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
                ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
        } finally {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        }
    }
}
```

> vendor/module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Contact\Model\Mail" type="vendor\module\Model\Mail"/>
</config>
```

It ran into this file, but it failed because some private variables.

Any help? Thank in advance.

Comment: try thi s link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/magento-2-3-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3-use-zendframework-2/298001#298001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code **etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Contact\Model\Mail"
        type="Vendor\Module\Model\Mail" />
```

Add 2 dependency in your  **Vendor/Module/Model/Mail.php**

```
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
```

Check below code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;

class Mail implements MailInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $contactsConfig;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StateInterface
     */
    private $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param ConfigInterface $contactsConfig
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param StoreManagerInterface|null $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->contactsConfig = $contactsConfig;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Send email from contact form
     *
     * @param string $replyTo
     * @param array $variables
     * @return void
     */
    public function send($replyTo, array $variables)
    {
        /** @see \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::validatedParams() */
        $replyToName = !empty($variables['data']['name']) ? $variables['data']['name'] : null;

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($variables)
                ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
                ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
                ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
        } finally {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        }
    }
}
```

You can check your core functionality override or not using below command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, it work for me.

Comment: most welcome....!

Answer (score 2):

As i see i think you probably want to override SEND method.

But i think the best practice is to use Plugin to change the thing as you want.

It will be safe in the future

Otherwise, if you still want to override the original class , you have to re-define all private variables to use again in the new class.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, I think you can create your own class(duplicate with public variables) in your custom module and set the preference in di.xml file of your custom module.

Add the following element in your custom module **di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Contact\Model\Mail"
            type="Vendor\CustomModule\Model\Mail" />
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi @Sudhanshu Bajaj please check update answer, Thanks