# Missing required argument $to of Magento\\Framework\\Mail\\EmailMessage. Magento 2.3.4

Tags: email, magento2.3.4

I was sending custom emails in magento version 2.3.2 successfully with below code:

```
$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $stroreid = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $error = false;
        $to = array($email);
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('template_name_here')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => $stroreid,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $variable])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($to)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

But after upgrade to version 2.3.4, when this sendEmail() function is executed I am getting error:

> "message": "Missing required argument $to of
>   Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage.",

By comparing vendor folders of 2.3.2 and 2.3.4 I noticed

```
 Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage
```

above class is new in 2.3.4 and has the following checks:

```
$mimeMessage = new ZendMimeMessage();
        $mimeMessage->setParts($body->getParts());
        $this->zendMessage->setBody($mimeMessage);
        if ($subject) {
            $this->zendMessage->setSubject($subject);
        }
        if ($sender) {
            $this->zendMessage->setSender($sender->getEmail(), $sender->getName());
        }
        if (count($to) < 1) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Email message must have at list one addressee');
        }
        if ($to) {
            $this->zendMessage->setTo($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($to));
        }
        if ($replyTo) {
            $this->zendMessage->setReplyTo($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($replyTo));
        }
        if ($from) {
            $this->zendMessage->setFrom($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($from));
        }
        if ($cc) {
            $this->zendMessage->setCc($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($cc));
        }
        if ($bcc) {
            $this->zendMessage->setBcc($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($bcc));
        }
        $this->mimeMessageFactory = $mimeMessageFactory;
        $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
```

I am trying to solve the issue by successfully sending email in 2.3.4. Can somebody check it also!

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/magento-2-3-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3-use-zendframework-2/298001#298001

Answer (score 4):

Error was, I was passing ***$to*** value in array as:

```
$to = array($email);
```

Which was working in version 2.3.2. Now I changed it to:

```
$to = $email;
```

It solved the error in 2.3.4. I hope it helps others.

Comment: Work on 2.4! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it's working for me in `Magento 2.3.4`

```
$email = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope);
$subject = 'ABC';
$from = array('email' => $email, 'name' => $subject);
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['data'] = $variable;
$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
$templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('template_name_here')
    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
    ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->addTo('aaa@bbb.com')
    ->getTransport();

try {
    $transport->sendMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```