# Send the Email attachment in the Email

Tags: magento2, email

I need to attach HTML file. I have dynamic HTML content and attach the HTMl content in the email

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/magento-2-3-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3-use-zendframework-2/298001#298001

Comment: how to create dynamic html file and upload in the attachment of the email

Comment: Please Describe more for better Understanding. and also add code you try.

Comment: I have add the content of html content of product name and price and qty and conert this content into html and send the email

Comment: your email is works ? please check it by add static content and check it. and also check attechment is works or not ? after  all this information i give you solution

Comment: email is working , but attachment is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105971/discussion-between-msquare-and-divya).

Comment: generate HTML file and send this file as attechment in email ?

Comment: let me inform it's helps you ?

Comment: You have also give me vote up for my affort to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please add one di.xml preference according to your Magento version** [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/magento-2-3-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3-use-zendframework-2/298001#298001)

then use below code to send Email with dynamic HTML Attechment file.

```
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $directoryList;
    protected $file_io;

    public function __construct(
        ............................................................
        ............................................................
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $file_io,
        ............................................................
        ............................................................
    ) {
        ............................................................
        ............................................................
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->file_io = $file_io;
        ............................................................
        ............................................................
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        ............................................................
        ............................................................
        ............................................................
        // create  html file 

        $filePath = "/attachment/file/";
        $pdfPath = $this->directoryList->getPath('media').$filePath;

        $ioAdapter = $this->file_io;
        if (!is_dir($pdfPath)) {
            $ioAdapter->mkdir($pdfPath, 0775);
        }
        $fileName = "FileName.html";
        $pdfContent = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML CONTENT</title></head>
        <body><table>
            <tr>
                <td>Product Name</td>
                <td>Product Price</td>
                <td>Product Qty</td>
            </tr>";

        /// get your products using for loop
        $pdfContent .= "<tr>
                    <td>TEst Product3333</td>
                    <td>2345</td>
                    <td>233333</td>
                </tr>";

        /*
        foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
                $pdfContent .= "<tr>
                    <td>".$value->getName()."</td>
                    <td>".$value->getPrice()."</td>
                    <td>".$value->getQty()."</td>
                </tr>";
        }
        */ 

        $pdfContent .= "</table></body></html>";
        $ioAdapter->open(array('path'=>$pdfPath));
        $ioAdapter->write($fileName, $pdfContent, 0666);


        // send Email 

        $template_name = "your Email Template Name";

        $template_var = [];
        $template_var['var1'] = "value1";

        $sender_email = "Sender Email";

        $reciever_email['email'] = "Reciever Email";
        $reciever_email['name'] = "Reciever Name";


        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        try {
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template_name)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
                ->setTemplateVars($template_var)
                ->setFrom($sender_email)
                ->addTo($reciever_email['email'], $reciever_email['name']);

            // get email attechment path
            $media = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
            $media .= "/attachment/file/";
            $file_url = $media."".$fileName;
            $file_content = file_get_contents($file_url);
            $file_info = $this->file_io->getPathInfo($file_url);
            $file_name = $file_info['basename'];
            $file_type = "text/html";

            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->addAttachment($file_content, $file_name, $file_type);

            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Email send fail'));
        }

        ............................................................
        ............................................................
        ............................................................
    }
}
```

> **NOTE: without adding preference in di.xml to this link Attechemnt not work, so please add this from** [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/magento-2-3-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3-use-zendframework-2/298001#298001)

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: I have to avoid Prefernce I have to use Plugin , but it shows the error

Comment: you must have to use preference  and add like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/magento-2-3-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3-use-zendframework-2/298001#298001

Comment: that's why a added note in my answer becuse without your attechment not working

Comment: Instead of prefernce I have to use plugin

Comment: <type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder">
            <plugin name="Vendor_module::attachment" type="Vendor\module\Model\Mail\TransportBuilder"/>

Comment: without prefernce  it's not works. you must use <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="[Vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\Mail\Template\AddEmailAttachemnt" />

Comment: In the TransportBuilder, I have added the attachment code, bit throw error. with the help of preference it works fine, I don't want to override whole Magento core file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105995/discussion-between-divya-and-msquare).