# Magento 2.4 - Send email with attachments

Tags: magento2, php, email, attachment, email-attachment

I am trying to send the emails with the attached files but I am not succeeding.

For the moment this is my code:

```
<?php
 
namespace PHPCuong\CustomerAccount\Helper;
 
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
 
class SendEmail extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $storeManager;
 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function sendEmailTransport(){
        return $this->transportBuilder;
    }

}
```

And this is the code for sending an email:

```
<?php
                        $helperLogEmail = $this->helper('\PHPCuong\CustomerAccount\Helper\SendEmail');

                        $templateId = 'customer_logo_ord'; // template id
                        $fromEmail = 'test@test.eu';  // sender Email id
                        $fromName = 'test'; // sender Name
                        $toEmail = "john.doe@company.eu";

                        $templateVars = [
                            'product_name' => '',
                            'order_id' => $orderInc
                        ];
             
                        $storeId = $_order->getStoreId();
             
                        $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
             
                        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
                        $templateOptions = [
                            'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                            'store' => $storeId
                        ];
                        
                        $transport = $helperLogEmail->sendEmailTransport()->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, $storeScope)
                            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                            ->setFrom($from)
                            ->addTo($toEmail)
                            ->addCc($fromEmail,'')
                            ->getTransport();
                            
                        //$helperLogEmail->sendEmailTransport()->addAttachment($fileName, 'image/jpeg');
                            
                            
                        $transport->sendMessage();
                        ?>
```

Now, how can i do for create and send attachments in my email with transport builder?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/magento-2-3-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3-use-zendframework-2/298001#298001

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addAttachment` to attach files while sending emails.

```
->addAttachment($filePath, $fileName);
```

Make sure to give filepath as **Relative Paths** like /var/www/html/yoursite/yourfile.xyz

Comment: addAttachment is a function that already exists in transport builder or do I have to create it myself? Thanks

Comment: that is already exits. for now add it after ->addCc($fromEmail,'') this one without ;

Comment: I tried man but return addAttachment() is not defined! How can i do? thanks!

Comment: where you have added addAttachment() function? can you update your question ?