# How to send inquiry email to customer on admin reply in magento2.4.3

Tags: module, database, custom, email-templates

Hello all magento developers, I want to send inquiry email notification to customer when admin can add reply to customer inquiry in magento 2.4.3.

can anyone have idea then please share here, Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257117/magento-2-3-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3-use-zendframework-2/298001#298001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding well you want to reply back to the customer.

You can use transport object and set email and name.

```
$this->transportBuilder->setReplyTo(
        $this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail(),
        $this->identityContainer->getCustomerName()
);
```