# Magento 2 How to send an email with attachment?

Tags: email, customer-account, magento2.3.1

How to send an email with attachment ?
i know there is already available on stackexchange but it is for below magento 2.3 version not for magento 2.3 or magento 2.3.1 version.

i already check this - [Magento 2: send email with Attachment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104044/magento-2-send-email-with-attachment)

but not working because addAttachment() & createAttachment() function is not present in magento2.3.1(zend framework 1 have no function now )

Please guide me - 
how to send an email with attachment ?

Comment: https://extait.com/blog/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3/

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar i tried that code but it gives errors and i also create a issue on github - https://github.com/extait-com/email-attachment/issues/3