# Email Attachment is not work for magento 2.3.1

Tags: email, attachment

I have try to send email with PDF attachment but not work in magento 2.3.1.
I am looking for some reference link:

[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104044/magento-2-send-email-with-attachment](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2019/05/22/sending-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3-x/)

[excellencemagentoblog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2019/05/22/sending-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3-x/)

and git link for [mageplaza/magento-2-email-attachments](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-email-attachments)

Please help me, if you have faces above issue and find the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link which will help you:
By pragmatically: 
**https://webkul.com/blog/attach-pdf-file-magento-2-email/**

By extension: 
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-email-attachments/

Comment: I have already use it but it is not work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working in my extension

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactAttachment

I based this off another tutorial. Sorry I can't find link.

```
    public function send($replyTo, array $variables)
    {
        $filePath = null;
        $fileName = null;
        $uploaded = false;

        try {
            $fileCheck = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'attachment']);
            $file = $fileCheck->validateFile();
            $attachment = $file['name'] ?? null;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $attachment = null;
        }

        if ($attachment) {
            $upload = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'attachment']);
            $upload->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $upload->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $upload->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $upload->setAllowedExtensions(['txt', 'csv', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx']);

            $path = $this->fileSystem
                ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
                ->getAbsolutePath(self::FOLDER_LOCATION);
            $result = $upload->save($path);
            $uploaded = self::FOLDER_LOCATION . $upload->getUploadedFilename();
            $filePath = $result['path'] . $result['file'];
            $fileName = $result['name'];
        }

        /** @see \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::validatedParams() */
        $replyToName = !empty($variables['data']['name']) ? $variables['data']['name'] : null;

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars($variables)
            ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
            ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
            ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
            ->getTransport();

        if ($uploaded && !empty($filePath) && $this->file->fileExists($filePath)) {
            $mimeType = mime_content_type($filePath);

            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                    ]
                )
                ->addAttachment($this->file->read($filePath), $fileName, $mimeType)
                ->setTemplateVars($variables)
                ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
                ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
                ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
                ->getTransport();
        }

        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    }
```