# How to magento 2 send xml file as a email attachment?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, I want to send custom XML file as an attachment in the email. How can I achieve this.

This is really urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a custom module.
Inside you need to create a class that implements the EmailNotificationInterface.
Following the magento guidelines you must use the \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder.

Here an example: [Magento 2: send email with Attachment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104044/magento-2-send-email-with-attachment)

Cheers

Comment: this solution worked. Thanks a lot