# Magento 2.2.11 - How to add attachment to an email, Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor::createAttachment() error

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, email, email-attachment

I have installed the pdf invoice Extension in Magento 2.2.11. I'm getting this error while placing the order,

> Call to undefined method
> Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor::createAttachment() in
> /app/code/MyVendor/PdfInvoice/Model/TransportBuilder.php:19

**MyVendor/PdfInvoice/Model/TransportBuilder.php**

```
<?php 

namespace MyVendor\PdfInvoice\Model;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /**
    * @param Api\AttachmentInterface $attachment
    */
    public function addAttachment($pdfString, $type = '')
    {
        $fileattached =  @file_get_contents($pdfString);
        $this->message->createAttachment(
            $fileattached,
            'application/pdf',
            \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
            $type.'.pdf'
        );
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * clear header
     * @param $headername
     */
    public function clearHeader($headerName)
    {
        if (isset($this->_headers[$headerName])) {
            unset($this->_headers[$headerName]);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> **When I replace this below code,**

```
$this->message->createAttachment(
            $fileattached,
            'application/pdf',
            \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
            $type.'.pdf'
        );
```

> **with this code**

```
$attachment = new \Zend\Mime\Part($fileattached);
        $attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
        $attachment->disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
        $attachment->encoding = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
        $attachment->filename = $type.'.pdf';
        return $attachment;
```

**Emails are sending but the attachment is not included in the mail.**

I have tried the below solution but didn't work.

[Magento 2.3 custom email attachment not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252506/magento-2-3-custom-email-attachment-not-working)

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-email-attachments/issues/4

**Let me know if anyone has any ideas.**

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/104044

Comment: @Msquare I have added the code like this https://nimbusweb.me/nimbus-screenshots/6ee77d43bf7126587b1c53b5823bcdf2 it's showing error https://nimbusweb.me/nimbus-screenshots/dc56ca4fe1fa2193208ef556073ae52f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally, I have figured it out. I made it work in Magento 2.2.11. I Had to make some changes to the `TransportBuilder.php` file.**

Followed this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/274723/73212 and now it's working.

> **TransportBuilder.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\PdfInvoice\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\Part as MimePart;
use Zend\Mime\PartFactory as MimePartFactory;
use Zend\Mime\Message as MimeMessage;
use Zend\Mime\MessageFactory as MimeMessageFactory;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /** @var MimePart[] */
    private $parts = [];

    /** @var MimeMessageFactory */
    private $mimeMessageFactory;

    /** @var MimePartFactory */
    private $mimePartFactory;

    public function __construct(
        FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
        MessageInterface $message,
        SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory,
        MimePartFactory $mimePartFactory,
        MimeMessageFactory $mimeMessageFactory,
        MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $templateFactory,
            $message,
            $senderResolver,
            $objectManager,
            $mailTransportFactory,
            $messageFactory
        );

        $this->mimePartFactory    = $mimePartFactory;
        $this->mimeMessageFactory = $mimeMessageFactory;
    }

    protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        parent::prepareMessage();

        $mimeMessage = $this->getMimeMessage($this->message);

        foreach ($this->parts as $part) {
            $mimeMessage->addPart($part);
        }

        $this->message->setBody($mimeMessage);

        return $this;
    }

    public function addAttachment($body, $type = '')
    {
        $fileattached =  @file_get_contents($body);
        $mimeType = 'application/pdf';
        $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
        $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
        $this->parts[] = $this->createMimePart($fileattached, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $type.'.pdf');

        return $this;
    }

    private function createMimePart(
        $content,
        $mimeType = 'application/pdf',
        $disposition = Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename = null
    ) {
        /** @var MimePart $mimePart */
        $mimePart = $this->mimePartFactory->create(['content' => $content]);
        $mimePart->setType($mimeType);
        $mimePart->setDisposition($disposition);
        $mimePart->setEncoding($encoding);
        $mimePart->setFileName($filename);
        if ($filename) {
            $mimePart->setFileName($filename);
        }

        return $mimePart;
    }

    private function getMimeMessage(MessageInterface $message)
    {
        $body = $message->getBody();

        if ($body instanceof MimeMessage) {
            return $body;
        }

        /** @var MimeMessage $mimeMessage */
        $mimeMessage = $this->mimeMessageFactory->create();

        if ($body) {
            $mimePart = $this->createMimePart($body, 'application/pdf', Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT);
            $mimeMessage->setParts([$mimePart]);
        }

        return $mimeMessage;
    }
    /**
     * clear header
     * @param $headername
     */
    public function clearHeader($headerName)
    {
        if (isset($this->_headers[$headerName])) {
            unset($this->_headers[$headerName]);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link can help you:
[How to magento 2 send xml file as a email attachment?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318627/how-to-magento-2-send-xml-file-as-a-email-attachment/318689#318689)

if you have any question ask here in comments

Comment: I have already tried this but didn't work

Comment: i have added the code like this https://nimb.ws/l5AsIt it's showing error https://nimb.ws/eHQ4n3

Comment: Also i'm using magento 2.2.11